# How to check if Flink task is backpressured programmatically

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Using Flink 1.11. I have a requirement to identify if a Flink task is facing back pressured. Using webui , we can monitor backpressure status. Is there any way to check in Flink Application if a particular task is facing backpressure ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Flink Job Manager REST API to get back-pressure information: https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/ops/rest_api/#jobs-jobid-vertices-vertexid-backpressure

```
/jobs/:jobid/vertices/:vertexid/backpressure

Returns back-pressure information for a job, and may initiate back-pressure sampling if necessary.
```

Comment: I want to check from a processFunction or mapFunction whether current task is backpressured or not. Is it possible ?

Comment: Ah I misunderstood then. You mean from within the task without calling the job manager. I'm not aware of any way to easily do it as you'd like. You could try to setup a source that periodically fetches that data from the JM and feeds it into to the operators but it doesn't seem straightforward to do.